# Symfony 2: can't get response from query strings (basic example)

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to follow the Symfony Book and to get values from the inserted url. In my controller I have:

```
namespace Developer\MarkBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SimplestController extends Controller
{
public function simpleAction()
{
    return new Response('Simple Response');
}

public function getMeAction(Request $request, $page)
{
    $to_get = $request->query->get('page');
    var_dump($to_get);

    return new Response('gotcha!');
}

}
```

and in the routing configuration:

```
get_me:
    path:     /get_me/{page}/{title}
    defaults: {_controller: DeveloperMarkBundle:Simplest:getMe }
```

When I write /get_me/somepage/sometitle in the browser I should get the value 'somepage' for the $page variable. But the var_dump shows NULL. I do not know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to get those from the query string parameters, you can get those right from the route. As your route is defined as `/get_me/{page}/{title}` just make sure your action is picking those up as arguments...

```
public function getMeAction(Request $request, $page, $title)
{
    return new Response("page is $page and title is $title");
}
```

See the manual section about [Routing with Placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#routing-with-placeholders) for more details

Also, note that if you're not using the Request object, you can omit that from the method arguments, making it look even simpler...

```
public function getMeAction($page, $title)
{
    return new Response("page is $page and title is $title");
}
```

Comment: Quick on the draw. +1

Comment: O.K. that works. But can I somehow get the placeholder from the URL by using $request->query->get('page') ?

Comment: You could if the URL had a query string `?page=foo` - given that Symfony has made it easy, why are you trying to make it hard? Sounds like there's a *different* problem you're trying to solve maybe?

Comment: no, I just wanted to practice the Response object. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getMeAction(Request $request, $page, $title)
{
    var_dump($page); // returns somepage

    return new Response('gotcha!');
}
```